# Strange voltage decay with clipper

Tags: voltage, synchronization

I need to limit the voltage coming out of the sync function on my radio signal generator so I can plug it into my laptop's audio input. This is what it looks like without any voltage limits:

[image]

I used a symmetrical clipper circuit with a 1.1K resistor and two diodes with 0.7V voltage drops to limit it. (I don't have enough rep to post a schematic, but if you google "symmetrical clipper circuit" click the first link and scroll down to the third image.)

Theoretically it should hold the voltage at 0.7V and it does when I use a waveform generator and give it a 10V peak to peak sine wave at 1kHz. But when I decrease the voltage I'm giving it, but still keep the voltage above the 0.7V cutoff, the peak to peak range decreases.

The really strange thing is that when I use it to limit the sync output, the function seems to decay. The later pulses cannot even be seen. When I tried using different resistors I still had the decay problem. Also the peak to peak voltage is more than the 0.7V it theoretically should be.

[image]

I suspected that the frequency was too high for the diodes, but I tried lowering the frequency of the sync output very low, to less than 1Hz and it still produced a similar result. I have read a few different questions here about clippers and articles about them, but none seem to mention this decay. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first picture looks to me like the AC coupling on the scope input is seriously affecting the waveform.  Try viewing the waveform with the scope set to DC coupling.

Comment: 1) What does the raw output look like 2) What does your schematic look like (with all instruments included) 3) what does your experimental setup look like

Comment: 1) The raw output is the first image. That is straight from the signal generator sync function to the scope. 2) Signal generator>clipper circuit>scope http://i.stack.imgur.com/MKTRK.jpg 3) Signal generator>breadboard with clipper>scope

Comment: Here's some rep. +1.

Comment: Oscilloscope probes, in addition to the obvious metal tip, also have a ground clip. Have you considered attaching the diode circuit's ground to the signal generator ground, and then attaching the probe ground clip to your circuit's ground?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a schematic of the audio input. It will probably explain the behavior:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLwEy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think you're seeing the input capacitor discharging back into the 1.1k resistor.

Comment: What you are seeing on the scope is not attached to the audio input. I have only taken the sync output from the signal generator put it through the clipper circuit and used the scope to examine the output. There is no capacitor in my circuit. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your D1 & D2 diodes with a single 50 ohm resistor. Remove (short out) R1. Your generator is probably outputting a 1V sync pulse but your scope seems to be "seeing" an unterminated output. Also check your probe compensation. It looks like it hasn't been adjusted.

The signal you expect here looks like it should be 1V (terminated) and occur several hundred milliseconds apart - is this the sync for a sweep of sine frequencies on another output of the generator?